# UIActivityViewController completion handler is !completed when using AirDrop

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity, uiactivitytypeairdrop

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to share some text and url which works great when sending some text and a url.

I currently need to use the completion handler to perform additional actions depending whether the user cancelled the `UIActivityViewController` or actually sent something.

The completion handler (`activityViewController.completionHandler` for iOS 7 is deprecated in iOS 8 which is now `activityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler`) returns a `BOOL completed` value which correctly returns `true` when sending with `email` `sms` `Facebook` `Twitter` however when sending via `Airdrop` the user must press `Cancel` to dismiss the `UIActivityViewController` once sent and thus I always receive a `false` from the completion handler.

Does anyone know if there's a way of knowing that the user has sent using `Airdrop` when the `UIActivityViewController` is dismissed?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found something of interest for you but unfortunately I couldn't test it as AirDrop didn't want to function between my iDevices. Sorry about that.

Anyway, you could try `setCompletionWithItemsHandler` checking for `activityType`:

```
[activityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
    NSLog(@"completed: %@, \n%d, \n%@, \n%@,", activityType, completed, returnedItems, activityError);

}];
```

If `activityType` is of type `com.apple.airdrop.etc` (just a guess) then the user has tapped on the icon. Hope it can help.

Comment: You are correct thanks. When the `activityType` is airdrop, it still returns `completed=False` however it's enough to assume it was successful. Thank you.